# Marketing Cloud SQL String Formatting to Retrieve Only Part of Data

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I am importing a file data which cannot be edited from the source. I am trying to modify and extract the only needed information via Marketing Cloud SQL.

Below is the original file field data and the desired outcome.

| Original Field | Desired Outcome Field 1 | Desired Outcome Field 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ACCESSORIES, Categories:Women, Type_en:Accessories, Brand:Example, NECKLACE, Collection:123 | Women | Accessories |
| Categories:Men, SHORT SLEEVES, Type_en:T-shirts, CLOTHING, Collection, 132, Brand:Example2 | Men | T-shirts |

For Desired Outcome Field 1, I want to only get the value that begins with "Categories:" and end before the comma; similar for Desired Outcome Field 2, I want to only retrieve the value that begins with "Type_en:" and end before the comma.

Is it possible to do so within Marketing Cloud SQL?

Thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Cross Apply](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/) function to parse the delimited field values.

```SQL
SELECT
    a.Original_Field,
    SUBSTRING(a.Original_Field, b.categories_index, CHARINDEX(',', a.Original_Field, b.categories_index)- b.categories_index) AS categories,
    SUBSTRING(a.Original_Field, b.type_en_index, CHARINDEX(',', a.Original_Field, b.type_en_index)- b.type_en_index) AS type_en
FROM
    DE AS a
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT
        NULLIF(CHARINDEX('Categories:', a.Original_Field) + 11, 11) AS categories_index,
        NULLIF(CHARINDEX('Type_en:', a.Original_Field)+ 8, 8) AS type_en_index
    ) AS b
```

Output:

| Original_Field | categories | type_en |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ACCESSORIES, Categories:Women, Type_en:Accessories, Brand:Example, NECKLACE, Collection:123 | Women | Accessories |
| Categories:Men, SHORT SLEEVES, Type_en:T-shirts, CLOTHING, Collection, 132, Brand:Example2 | Men | T-shirts |

Try this: https://dbfiddle.uk/E8_lzeUK

You may want to read these articles since I just learned the function from there:

- [Parsing Delimited Fields Values with SQL Cross Apply](https://sprignaturemoves.com/parsing-delimited-fields-values-with-sql-cross-apply/)
- [Splitting a string of comma-separated values in a Data Extension field using SQL](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2023/05/08/splitting-a-string-of-comma-separated-values-in-a-data-extension-field-using-sql/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Duc! Also appreciate the article sharing :) It worked!

Comment: @HannahKim great to hear that. Can you mark it as an accepted answer then?

Comment: Thought I did earlier - just did it now! Thanks again!